# How to see if struct pointer in struct pointer is initialized or not

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct like the following:

```
typedef struct {
    player *lastmover;
    player *previous;
} lastmove;


typedef struct {
     int moves;
     char *name;
} player;
```

I try do a memory alloc like this so the :

```
lastmove lmv;
lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player *));
lmv.previous=malloc(sizeof(player *));
.....
callfunction(&lmv);
.....
```

then in another place i use a pointer lmvp (lastmover *) and do assignment like this:

```
void
callfuntion(lastmove *)
{
      .....
      lmvp->previous=lmvp->lastmover;
      lmvp->lastmover=p;     //where p is of type (player *)
      .....
}
```

this all works fine, but I don't know how to control weather previous mover is initialized. In the first game move in the program the lastmover variable (player *) is initialized, but the previous variable that is assigned to NULL(or garbage?) `lmvp->previous=lmvp->lastmover;`. But I want somehow to check if the previous mover is initialized or not. Im trying this:

```
void
callfunction(lastmove *)
{
     ......
     ......
     if(lmvp->previous!=NULL)
     ......
}
```

But im quite certain it will not do.. How is the best way to control this?

Comment: Just make sure you explicitly make the pointer `NULL` every time `lastmover` does not exist and it should work fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player));` (and not `player *`)?

Comment: @Als but thats the problem I don't know how to check if the `lastmover` exist or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're only allocating size of pointer, this

```
lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player *));
```

Should be

```
lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player));
```

> this all works fine

it shouldn't :)

Edit:
if you only assign a pointer to `lastmover` then you don't need to allocate memory at all, otherwise it's a memory leak, now if you want to check if it's initialized then initialize it to `NULL`

```
lastmove lmv = {0};
//or
lmv.lastmover= NULL;
lmv.previous= NULL;
...
//later
if(lmv->previous!=NULL)
```

A third way to do it, in C99, is using designated initializers:

```
lastmove lmv = {
   .lastmover= NULL;
   .previous= NULL;
};
```

Comment: But I have run the code and it actually works. I never assign a player type to the lastmover. I only assign pointers to it. Isn't that ok?

Comment: @patriques if you only assign pointers, then you don't need to allocate memory at all.

Comment: In fact, if you allocate memory and assign it to a pointer, then overwrite the pointer (make it point elsewhere), you 'leak' allocated memory. Also: Learn to love `valgrind`.

Comment: trying to learn loving gdb instead, but maybe valgrind is better?

Comment: @patriques gdb is a debugger, valgrind is used mainly for profiling and a memory leaks, among a few other thing and yes you need to love them both equally :)

Comment: @patriques - Both are great tools. `valgrind` is 'different' (neither better nor worse). It profiles executions, and catches a lot of nasty/harmless memory problems, even if the program *seems to work* somehow. They can be used in conjunction, depending on the problem at hand.

Comment: @mux - My original comment was for the OP. Anyway, nice you included that bit.

Comment: @ArjunShankar I was a little reluctant to introduce new terms, but it's better to know now I guess :)

Comment: A better idiom is to use `lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof *lmv.lastmover);` instead of `lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player));`.  It will always work, even if the type of `lastmover` changes.

Comment: @tomlogic that's a very good point, but I'll leave it out of the answer as I really don't wish to complicate things further for the OP.

Comment: @tornlogic I updated my code to be more generic for the future, Its a good practice.

Comment: @mux I have updated my question to clarify my problem, I maybe was a bit unclear about my problem before.

Comment: @patriques not sure I understand, doesn't the above answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player));
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say that lmv is by now a pointer to a lastmover. I updated the question, but thank you for pointing it out

Comment: A better idiom is to use `lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof *lmv.lastmover);` instead of `lmv.lastmover=malloc(sizeof(player));`.  It will always work, even if the type of `lastmover` changes.